# Retrofit 2 ошибка в запросе?

Tags: android, retrofit

Ошибка

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 36 path
>   $.data[0].object

```
@GET("?act=auth")
Call<AuthResponse> auth(@Query("login") String login, @Query("password") String password);
```

Вот Json:

```
{"data":[{"success":true,"object":{"id":"18","phone":"(444)444-4444","dop_phone":"(222)111-1111","email":"abaaaba@mail.kz","name":"beka","city":"turkestan","address":"mkrTGJ","user_type":"0"},"errors":""}]}


btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number = eTxtUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = eTxtPassword.getText().toString();

            ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<AuthResponse> call =  apiInterface.auth(number,password);
            Log.i("ssss",""+call);
            if(call == null)
                Log.i("ssss",""+1);
            else
                Log.i("ssss",""+2);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {
                    Log.i("ssss",""+2322);

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<AuthResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.i("ssss",""+t);
                }
            });

        }
    });


  public class AuthResponse {

  @SerializedName("data")
  @Expose
  private List<DataAuth> data = new ArrayList<DataAuth>();

  @NonNull
  public List<DataAuth> getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(@NonNull List<DataAuth> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}


public class DataAuth {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private boolean success;
@SerializedName("object")
@Expose
private List<InfoClient> infoClients = new ArrayList<InfoClient>();
@SerializedName("errors")
@Expose
private String errors;

  public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
  }

  public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
  }

  public List<InfoClient> getInfoClients() {
    return infoClients;
  }

  public void setInfoClients(List<InfoClient> infoClients) {
    this.infoClients = infoClients;
  }

  public String getErrors() {
    return errors;
  }

  public void setErrors(String errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
  }
}

public class InfoClient {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("phone")
@Expose
private String phone;
@SerializedName("dop_phone")
@Expose
private String dopPhone;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("city")
@Expose
private String city;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;
@SerializedName("user_type")
@Expose
private String userType;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getDopPhone() {
    return dopPhone;
}

public void setDopPhone(String dopPhone) {
    this.dopPhone = dopPhone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }

  public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
  }

  public String getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
  }

  public void setUserType(String userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
  }
}
```

Comment: Проблема в ```AuthResponse``` Покажите код этого класса.

Comment: добавил код посмотрите

Comment: класс DataAuth покажите

Comment: добавил код.....

Answer (score 0):

В классе `DataAuth` поле `private List<InfoClient> infoClients` должно быть обычным объектом, т.е `private InfoClient infoClients`

Comment: Исправил но все равно выходит ошибка Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 37 path $.data[0].object

Comment: @Mr.Baga сейчас структура классов должна полностью соответствовать JSON'у, посмотрите все ли вы правильно исправили и приложите обновленный код к вопросу.